# Why not implement a delay to putting a topic on hold so the poster can have time to edit their question?

Tags: support, feature-request

I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow and I like the community so far. I'm all on board for having the **[hold]** and **[closed]** features when posts are off-topic and/or vague. But, I don't like how fast you can take down someones post without giving them time to edit it.

I recently made a post regarding a question about code reuseability, and while I'm busy doing other things, my question was put on hold quite fast for being too vague and confusing. Now no-one is allowed to comment or answer my question until it has been reviewed. I re-edited it with resources and made it more constructive and less confusing and now I'm in what I like to call limbo.

I learned that all posts put on hold are sent to a review queue where other users with at least 4, 000 reputation points are allowed to upvote these on hold questions and after about 6 or so upvotes the question is allowed to be answered again. But until then, I have to wait at most 5 days for enough people to review my question.

This all could have been avoided if we were allowed time to edit our questions before they're taken down. Instead, mine was sent almost instantly to the grave yard. Now I'm not saying my question should be put back up, but I'm sure there are other questions that are really good questions that were just asked in the wrong way. Do those questions deserve to not be answered for a whole week if not at all? Why not give them at least half a day or more to make the needed corrections before taking down a potentially good topic?

Comment: Don't post your question until you have it ready. Putting questions "on hold" is by design. We hope that you then edit your question to acceptable standards and then after your edit it will be place in the reopen queue for it to be decided whether to reopen or not. We don't want people answering broad/unclear questions with broad/general answers. That is why it's put on hold until the questioner fixes their question.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. People can still comment on your post when your question has been put on hold. Also, just a nitpick: it needs 5 reopen votes (different to upvotes) from users with >3k rep to get your post reopened (either from the queue or by visiting the question itself).

Comment: @Roombatron5000 Exactly it's by design. And designs should be allowed to be extended when they can be made better. I'm not saying get rid of the current design, I'm saying add on to it and make it a better design. This is suppose to be a website to share information, not a site to shut people up when they don't ask a question perfectly.

Comment: I know, let's not!

Comment: Yes, we do want to shut people up when they ask shit questions (not imperfect ones as you claim).  This is because shit questions drive away people who provide good answers.  The help vampires, the lazy, the perpetually clueless, the unwilling-to-improves, the list goes on and on.  If you give them enough rope, they'll hang *you* with their BS.  Screw them.  It is almost trivial to ask a decent question.  I see noobs do it every day.  Hell, you did it here.  Was it so damned hard?  No.  Expecting people who want others to help them for free to show effort is not much to ask at all.

Comment: [Wow, a guy with 24 rep asking a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552516/why-and-how-can-an-object-file-of-old-code-use-new-code-that-uses-the-generic-pr).  Hell, you put about 2000% more effort into that than is necessary to stay open. Also, I see your *real* problem... you're posting C++ questions.  People in the C++ tag are ... you know how C++ devs are, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's two misconceptions here.

First, **your question hasn't been sent to the graveyard.**  Much like any other question which is edited after it's closed, it's sent back into the Reopen queue, where someone has a chance to look at it to see if it's suitable to be reopened.

Second, **if your question isn't fully baked, there's no benefit to either you or anyone else in asking it.**  It's not that you need to know everything before you ask, but if you've got a question which is incomplete, then you should wait until your question becomes more complete to ask it.

Stack Overflow [has a ***lot*** of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).  Some of these questions are exemplary and have risen to the surface as go-to references.  Most of these questions simply aren't.  A subset of those that aren't exemplary have a chance of *becoming* exemplary if the question is made clearer and brought on-topic.  The hope is that those that have a chance to become exemplary will benefit from the period in which they were on hold, and get someone else to look at it.

If you need a moment before you ask your question, please take it **before** you post the question.

Comment: After 5 days if my question has not been allowed for reopen am I allowed to repost my edited question or am I forever not allowed to ever ever ask that question again?

Comment: @WanderingIdiot - There is no such thing as a number of days for which a closed question is automatically opened again.

Answer (score 7):

You can impose this delay on yourself by simply not posting the question until it's in shape to be a good question (for me, 72 hour delay... which means [I almost never ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2792531/nhgrif?tab=questions)).

Moreover, being put [on hold] is placing a delay on *answers* posted to the question until the question is in shape to be a good question for the site.  The [on hold] status is designed *exactly* for giving users a chance to improve their question and avoid its deletion.

Comment: Alot of times I don't know when a question is in good shape for posting, but I do know what changes to give to it after people tell me why it's not good enough. What I'm trying to say is I need the feedback sometimes to know how to make my question better before I post it. And I can't do that if it's being put on hold right as soon as I post it.

Comment: @WanderingIdiot - "Alot of times I don't know when a question is in good shape for posting" Then you need to work on asking better questions.

Comment: @WanderingIdiot *"I can't do that if it's being put on hold right as soon as I post it."* - yes, you can. That's exactly what you *should* do; on hold questions are editable for this reason.

Comment: @WanderingIdiot The first time you click on "Ask a Question", type in a rough draft of your question.  But don't actually post it.  Your question will be saved.  You can leave and come back to it.  Now, when you've finished typing the rought draft, start a 72 hour timer.  999 times out of 1000, if you continue to work at that problem, you'll be able to discard that question without ever even asking it.  And the remaining chances, you'll end up with a pretty good question (if you continue to improve your draft).

Comment: If you follow that advice, you may still have people ask for more detail, but when they see the effort you've made *before* the first post of the question, they'll give more of a benefit of the doubt before closing (generally).  You may still need to add more details.  Consider the edit history on [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26674111/revisions).  I had to add a lot of details based on comments.  But [the original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/227a31b9-c35d-4296-b879-d09000c900dc/view-source) never got any close votes as it already started as a question

Comment: that looked like it had a lot of effort put into it, with plenty of research done, and it wasn't unclear what I was asking.